# which-function-mode and modified mode line

Tags: mode-line, quote, which-function-mode

I modified my mode-line, but now `which-function-mode` stopped working: nothing is displayed.  Code:

```
(setq mode-line-position
      (list '(:eval (propertize "L%l " 'face nil 'help-echo "Line number"))
            '(:eval (propertize "C%C " 'face nil 'help-echo "Column number"))
            (list -3 (propertize "%P" 'face nil 'help-echo "Position in buffer"))
            '(:eval (when (buffer-file-name)
                      (propertize "  %I" 'face 'font-lock-variable-name-face
                                  'help-echo "Buffer size")))))

(setq mode-line-modified
      (list '(:eval (propertize "%*" 'face nil 'help-echo
                                "Buffer read-only and modification indicator"))
            '(:eval (propertize "%+" 'face nil 'help-echo
                                "Buffer read-only and modification indicator"))))

(setq mode-line-buffer-identification
      (list '(:eval (propertize "%12b" 'face 'mode-line-buffer-id
                                'help-echo default-directory))))

(setq-default mode-line-format
              (list "%e"
                    mode-line-position "  "
                    mode-line-modified "  "
                    mode-line-buffer-identification "  "
                    mode-line-modes "  "
                    mode-line-misc-info
                    ))

(which-function-mode)
```

`which-function-mode` uses `mode-line-misc-info`, which I did not modify.
Its value is

```
((which-function-mode
  (which-func-mode
   (#1="" which-func-format " ")))
 (global-mode-string
  (#1# global-mode-string " ")))
```

Why isn't it showing anything then? (Nothing is displayed if Emacs is started with this code as `~/.emacs`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't evaluate list when you set `mode-line-format`. Use `'` instead of `list`:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
              '("%e"
                mode-line-position "  "
                mode-line-modified "  "
                mode-line-buffer-identification "  "
                mode-line-modes "  "
                mode-line-misc-info
                ))
```

At the moment you set `mode-line-format` there are no `which-function-mode` related code in the `mode-line-misc-info`.

See [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html).

Comment: That's it, thank you, it works now.